# Как вывести схожие строки по значению параметра?

Tags: delphi, sql

Надо сделать запрос на вывод в виде таблицы в Delphi. Есть код запроса:

```
Query1.Active := False;
Query1.SQL.Clear;
Query1.SQL.Add('select * from table1 where nazvanie like ' +chr(39) + Edit2.Text + chr(39));
Query1.Active := true;
```

Когда я ввожу название, к примеру, `пила`, он мне делает выборку и выдает `пила` и + все значения по полям. Надо сделать так чтоб, если в поле есть `пила`, `пила 2`, `пила 3`, то они выводились по схожести: `пила`, `пила 2`, `пила 3`.

Comment: Если мне нужно было фильтровать записи по набранному в edit тексту, то я бы это сделал с помощью фильтрации. И ещё, не очень понятно в самом запросе, где написано table1 - это название таблицы в БД или так компонент называется?

Comment: ет таблица,и если можно напишите код фильтрации

Answer (score 1):

В обработчике события OnChange компонента Edit нужно написать код.

```
procedure TDataBaseForm.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If (Edit1.Text = '') Then
    Table1.Filtered:=True
  Else 
    Table1.Filtered:=False;
  Table1.Filter:='Название поля (то которое в таблице БД, в Вашем случае nazvanie) > '+QuotedStr(EditFind.Text); 
end;
```

А в обработчике OnFilterRecord набора данных (таблицы Table или запроса) такой код.

```
procedure TForm1.Table1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet;
  var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept:=False;
  If (Copy(<имя поля (в инспекторе объекта посмотреть можно)>.AsString,
    1,  Length(Edit1.Text))=
    Edit1.Text) Then Accept:=True;
end;
```

Если всё правильно, то при вводе в Edit начальной части слова, данные в таблице должны фильтроваться. Например, если в Edit-е написана одна буква, то в таблице будут видны записи, начинающиеся с неё.

Answer (score 0):

'select * from table1 where nazvanie like  ' + Edit2.Text + '% ORDER BY nazvanie'